Can I use AI to help me answer as long as the actual content isn't AI-generated?
Suppose I use generative AI to help me answer a question, but I don't actually copy any of the verbiage output by the AI into my post - i.e. suppose that I'm using it merely as a source of information that I then verify and write up in my own words. Have I broken the generative AI ban?
The state of the rules around this is, it seems to me, pretty unclear.
Simply taking the policy entirely literally, the answer would seem to be yes - it says, after all, that "All use of generative AI ... is banned" (emphasis mine), and use as a research assistant is still use.
On the other hand, there are a slew of reasons to immediately think this strict literal interpretation is surely not intended, just based on the policy post itself and on common sense:

The explanation in the policy post of why we ban GenAI doesn't really apply to this kind of use, or at least applies much less than it does to copying and pasting generated content:

The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies produce have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like the answers might be good and the answers are very easy to produce.


This strict interpretation creates a weird situation where - if I am following the rules strictly - some of my knowledge may become tainted and forbidden from posting on Stack Overflow, because I originally obtained it via some kind of GenAI use.

It would be very easy to break such a ban accidentally, by forgetting where I learned something, or by not knowing I'd used GenAI (e.g. relying on a response from a company's support team while being unaware the company has replaced their support team with a chatbot).

Elsewhere in the same policy post, the phrasing "the posting of content created by ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies" is used, which seems to refer specifically to copying GenAI output and not more broadly to using them in the course of crafting an answer.


Some discussion of this point has occurred elsewhere, but none of it seems to conclusively indicate how the mods are interpreting the policy:

Various answers to What might "responsible" (a.k.a. acceptable) use of AI look like on Stack Overflow? discuss this kind of GenAI usage or similar, and are upvoted. This indicates at least some community support for allowing "research assistant" AI usage. But this is certainly nowhere near to establishing that this is policy.

A very heavily downvoted, but in my view reasonable, important, and somewhat prescient answer on the policy post raises precisely this ambiguity, but it never really gets resolved. (In the comments, people variously respond in ways that suggest they're assuming only outright posting GenAI output is banned, or they dismiss the very idea that anyone would ever write their own post based on stuff they've learned through use of GenAI and thus dismiss the question as irrelevant.)

Another downvoted but really very sensible answer on the policy post asks about paraphrases of GenAI. In a highly-upvoted comment in response, Makyen says that direct paraphrases of GenAI outputs are banned, analogously to how a direct paraphrase of a third party source without citation would still be considered plagiarism just like a direct copy and paste would. Fair enough, but that still doesn't address indirect paraphrases or posts that are almost entirely the author's original work but make use of a couple of facts discovered with the help of GenAI.


The recent scandal around VonC's AI use highlights this ambiguity again and also makes it somewhat more urgent to resolve. I note a few things:

VonC's apology post - which many of the moderators have explicitly endorsed - notably does not explicitly admit, at any point, to ever copying and pasting GenAI output into a post, even once. Indeed it says explicitly that at least the primary way VonC used AI was as a research assistant, not as a content author:

I would like to sincerely apologize for the series of answers I posted ... which were based on outputs generated from an AI tool (before being reworked, researched, and sourced)

(emphasis mine)

In a comment on Stack Overflow, VonC says something that seems to back up the idea that even a post that merely uses knowledge he has obtained from use of GenAI is against the rules, even if it doesn't contain any GenAI content:

For obvious reason, I cannot repost an illegitimate answer, even reworded. But you should be able to see the deleted one, and post in your own word, based on your setup and experience, something which will help other readers.

(again, emphasis mine). So, whether or not he pasted content into his answers, and whether or not he's correct about what the policy is, I at least understand from this that VonC himself thinks that posting answers containing information that he obtained via GenAI for the purpose of answering the question is the thing that's against the rules, not merely posting actual GenAI output or close paraphrases of it.

Some of VonC's deleted answers, including the five highest-upvoted ones I link to at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430098/1709587, are almost entirely made up of attributed quotes from external sources, with only perfunctory commentary. Given that at least ChatGPT never generates content like this, and that VonC's own description of his AI use says that he researched and sourced these answers, it seems to me that we can fairly confidently infer that these answers are essentially entirely written by VonC, but may have used AI for research. Mod Machavity says we should flag deleted answers of VonC where there's a case to be made that they are not AI-generated, and I've duly flagged a couple of these answers, but the results were mixed; one post got undeleted in response to such a flag, and the other flag (on Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl) got declined with the message:

please don't take guesses; the only person who should be flagging these posts to clarify if/how much AI was employed is VonC himself

Machavity's advice of course only makes sense at all if it's only posting GenAI output that's banned, but the flag decline reason seems to suggest there's a stricter rule (with the consequence that we readers cannot possibly infer whether the rule was violated, even when looking at content that is clearly not GenAI-authored).


In summary: I'm confused! Some specific questions:

Is using GenAI for researching an answer banned, even if you don't copy or closely paraphrase any of its output?
Can VonC post new answers based on his deleted answers as long as they do not copy or close-paraphrase from them?
Can we post answers based on information from VonC's deleted answers?


How do you detect what source the author learned some fairly general piece of knowledge? IMHO the idea that having read something from some AI output "taints" that information forever doesn't make sense, and any such policy would be unenforceable.

This (ignoring the parts about VonC) has been discussed before but I can't seem to find the relevant posts. From what I remember though the moderators have expressed that you can use Generative AI for researching but you must not copy the generated content and you must validate your answer before posting. To be honest we don't really have a way to find out if someone did that anyway (posted an answer after using Gen AI to research).

Using AI as a research tool - since LLM's are trained on existing data that seems like cheating. However if you're writing the answer in your own words, I don't see how that could be different of any other form of research. I still see it as still unethical, but I don't see it to be against the rules.

@SecurityHound the question is whether things that you learned as a person by using GenAI and rewrote in your own words constitute "GenAI content".

Please don't use VonC as an example. It is a very bad one and completely not applicable for what you are trying to ask here. The lack of admission of direct copy pasting does not mean that it didn't happen.

@DalijaPrasnikar I'll take your word for it, but even if his conduct is a bad example of what I'm asking, VonC is still highly relevant here; he's pretty much the entire motivation for asking this question. Until VonC's case, it didn't matter if merely gaining knowledge from AI-generated content was technically banned, because nobody would ever know and so such a ban was unenforceable. Now we have a goldmine of deleted posts that may have violated the AI ban, on questions newly missing good answers. Reading those deleted posts will (indirectly) constitute gaining knowledge via GenAI. [1/2]

[2/2] So, it kinda matters now what the rules on this are and we can no longer shrug and ignore it. There are 1850 questions with missing answers for us to go and fix, but if I go and start answering them, referring to VonC's answers as I do so, it's going to be somewhere between extremely suspicious and incredibly obvious that I have gained information from GenAI (although even I won't know what information that was or which specific answers of mine will thus be tainted!), and I don't know if that's going to earn me answer deletions and a suspension.

I've found the whole VonC affair to be mostly confusing rather than clarifying or even neutral. There is a certain amount of something like legalistic reasoning in your question which I suppose is partly the point. My own interpretation is that it's ok to learn stuff from gen AI and then post answers based on that learning but in your own words, but make sure you learned it. That means understanding it, understanding your answer, and checking any code you provide. If you do that it's basically impossible to be accused of copying gen AI output.

Let me put it this way. Do you really think that you could pick any tech stack you are not knowledgeable in, then pick some non trivial question and answer it with the help of AI where you will not use what AI gave you, but with your newly gained knowledge? I am not even going into the fact that you cannot possibly gain knowledge from AI because it will consistently lie and deceive you. You cannot trust a word it says. Sometimes it will say things that may sound reasonable for non experts in the field and it will be so completely wrong.

The only way you can possibly use AI to gain knowledge, is to use it as a Google replacement where you will ignore literally anything it says in the summary (don't even read it) and just click on all the links it gives you as a reference and maybe you will be able to learn something.

Also if you need to read any post from any other user, deleted or undeleted, to answer some question, then you are probably the wrong person to be answering that question in the first place. I know this may sound a bit harsh, but this is the only thing I can say in the context of this question.

"you cannot possibly gain knowledge from AI because it will consistently lie and deceive you" - no, it will frequently lie and deceive you, but not consistently. In this way, it differs only in degree from the average Stack Overflow answerer. But we have the benefit of being a field where (usually) documentation is easily available and experimentation is trivially easy, which means we can verify the correctness of what we read and sort the truth from the garbage - whether it be AI-authored garbage or otherwise.

As to your final comment, @DalijaPrasnikar, I don't think I've ever answered a question without first reading the existing answers (how else would I know if I'm adding anything?) and I often learn something from doing so. It's also not unusual for me to begin trying to answer a question with little idea of the answer, and to need to spend hours or days and read multiple sources before putting together something worth posting. My answers are still well-received and, IMO, are good. So I put it to you that your view on who is fit to answer a question is wrong (and never mind if it's "harsh").

I am not entirely disagreeing with you, but I have to put it like that (harshly), because I cannot be more open for various reasons. I hope you will understand why I mean when I said that "if you don't know how to answer you rare not the right person to answer". Just do what you did before AI and you will be fine. That goes for everyone else.

Thank you for asking this question; I believe this unknown has silently hung in the air since the OG policy announcement, and past attempts to address it have been met with what's felt like marked backlash (and at times, seeming disagreement among the mod team as well, like the handling of your flags). GenAI feels like a Pandora's Box situation; I don't think we can just "go back to how we did answers before AI", especially as (if?) casual use of these tools becomes more prolific and common, whether by choice or by them being integrated in ways that aren't obvious to users.

@zcoop98 "especially as (if?) casual use of these tools becomes more prolific and common" - yeah, this is going to make the strictest possible interpretations of the rule completely insane and unreasonable. For instance, what if it turns out the primary author of the docs for some tool uses Copilot in her editor and it assists her in her doc writing? Probably if I wanted to go digging through blogs and Twitter accounts of prolific FOSS contributors, I could identify an example. Are we going to ban citing the docs? Ban anyone who has ever read the docs from answering questions about the tool?

(Well, "insane and unreasonable" by my lights, anyway. And yet we've got at least one user, @SecurityHound, insisting - I think - that yes, merely reading something that somebody else generated with AI means you are never allowed to answer anything using knowledge you gained by reading that content, and that this "could not be more clear". So, evidently my sense of what reasonable ways of construing the rules might be is not universally shared...)

very interesting question and discussion. AI is like humans in that both are fallible, without being aware of it (you aren't "lying" if you are merely careless in your claims). AI is just more fallible and more obviously fallible right now. half of science is others replicating or invalidating your claims. the AI ban has two goals: (1) don't pollute the data set with garbage, which became a lot easier to produce using AI (2) don't overburden the review process, which starts with regulars watching their tags and checking new answers for their quality (voting, critiquing, improving, answering).

my personal position has been, and continues to be, that I, as a fellow meatbag (40% anyway), use AI as a tool to assist me in some ways, but ultimately, if I claim that something is my work, I am responsible for all of it, so it's on me to make sure that my solutions work. in this technical context, that's easy. things are true or not, independent of the rest of the universe. I wouldn't trust AI output for any kind of literature review. "someone did something at some time"? I would either already be sure of this, or I'd have to chase down primary sources (we aren't Wikipedia...)

AI has the problems 1) that it is (too) cheap to produce. You can create pages of answers or codes within seconds. You put the burden on reviewers and take the fame. 2) it has dubious legal licenses. Even if OpenAI, Google or other companies say, you may use the code or answers: There is no proof that the code or answers was not taken literally from a source with a different license. You cannot publish any of that answers or code with the promise it was from you. 3) AI answers are optimized to look correct and authentic. Bugs are much harder to spot. AI ones are the worst kind of wrong answers

@DalijaPrasnikar: No comment on whether you can gain knowledge from an AI; however I can gain knowledge from an AI. I upvoted the question because it's a natural question about the policy I couldn't guess the answer to; however I find I have no bone in this fight. I don't post AI answers because the AI output is too alien to my nature.

@MarkAmery, ...at least over in the bash tag where I spent a bit of time, "experimentation is trivially easy" is a trap: there's lots of code that looks like it works but has major pitfalls (security bugs, portability limitations, cases where one needs data covering nonobvious test cases to uncover failures, etc). It takes experience to sift sound answers from unsound (and in bash in particular there's so much unsound content on the Internet, including on sites with a great deal of "Google juice", that it's genuinely a matter of significant expertise to sift the wheat from the chaff).

@CharlesDuffy Yeah, I certainly take the point that there are questions and answers like that, and I agree with you pointing to Bash by way of example; I find that Unix shell scripting is exceptionally laden with those kind of traps, more than any other kind of programming I've ever touched. Heck, just dealing with the possibility of there being whitespace in a variable when using it in a command is too much for most people to get right in Bash, and that's just one trap among so, so many...

There is good discussion here, but this is already covered by the policy, like every other question about using AI on SO. The big bold header at the top of the policy post says "All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow. This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers." which is exactly what you are asking. The answer to any question asking "can I use AI to post [...] on SO" is no.

@TylerH "which is exactly what you are asking" - how so? None of the examples of forbidden use listed after "This includes" match what I ask about in this question (indeed they're not even similar). The only bit that's pertinent is the bit that says "All use of generative AI ... is banned when posting content", and in this question itself I outlined at great length multiple reasons, including the wording of other parts of the very same policy, to think that that phrase is not intended to include use for research.

Even if you personally do think the correct interpretation is obvious and unambiguous, clearly I am not alone in disagreeing with you; the votes, comments, and answers here, as well as the evidence I array in the question itself, indicates that plenty of others users including mods either think the policy does not forbid use for research or are unsure. I think it's dodgy to close a question about how to interpret a policy as a duplicate of the policy itself even when all readers consider the policy unambiguous and the answer obvious, but that's not even the case here!

The policy does not forbid the use of research. Of course it doesn't. that's stupid. You can't ban where someone learned a given thing.

Outlining this idea as policy is a slippery slope, because strictly saying "Of course you can use AI to research" leads to bad actors going "Oh well i asked ai and it told me this so here's how you solve it enjoy, haha i paraphrased it so it's not technically AI!" it's best to leave the policy as is and let the exception handlers do their job.

The thing is even if the community wanted to forbid generative AI usage for research we couldn't. Because there's no way we can detect that. This question is in fact great because it asks for permission where it doesn't need to.

A silly point belatedly occurs to me that I wish I'd included in the original question: if the policy were indeed meant as a sweeping ban on even research use of AI, then the existence of the policy would itself be a violation of the policy, as would all reference to the policy, since the policy describes characteristics of GenAI output that could only be determined by someone using GenAI in the first place.

@TylerH I strongly detest the single-handed gold badge closure of this when it's generated useful discussion. Just because you personally believe the policy is clear does not mean others do, and the very fact that good discussion has occurred (which you even acknowledge) I think is testament enough that this discussion should stay open. There is very clearly perceived ambiguity in the policy here– even if the answer ends up "this shouldn't be specified in the policy", that's still useful to discuss. The policy post also doesn't at all address the VonC-specific points of this question.

@zcoop98 There's one edge case involved here, and the clear top answer says 'this is an edge case, not a rule, use good faith when interpreting the policy'. A moderator has also already weighed in and said 'please don't use VonC as an example' saying the example is flawed and also irrelevant to the scenario posed here. For those reasons and for the rest of the question's body, I think the question is a duplicate that is fully answered by the policy. I have a gold badge in [tag:discussion]. That's exactly how the feature is designed to work. No need to add noise about it being 'personal'.

@TylerH I just feel differently I suppose; I see discussing this policy edge case as a very useful meta discussion to have around the policy itself, and one I've personally seen silently brewing for a while. I didn't intend my comment as a slight to you, I apologize if it came across that way; I'm frustrated that what I see as a valid discussion has been halted so suddenly, is all. Asking "hey can we clarify this policy" and having it duped to the policy just feels deeply unconstructive and silly to me, especially when the "it's clear, just read the policy" perspective was already noted above.

@zcoop98 Fair enough; I will post an answer that hopefully makes it more clear that this is a duplicate of the comprehensive policy announcement.

Not sure if there was a comment from me here or not, so let me summarize that I strongly doubt that in the case of vonC really responsible use of GenAI took place. Given the carefulness that is necessary on the one hand and the big amount of GenAI generated content on the other hand, I find this unlikely. It might therefore not be the best example to use in this question, because we don't know how much work really went into these posts. A well vetted and rewritten post might even be indistinguishable from a non AI post.

Hard cases make bad policy.  Before I answer, I want to highlight what I see as an elephant in the room.  There is tremendous skepticism about anything GenAI related on Stack Overflow.  And for good reason.  And, to me, your question  sounds like it is inviting us down a path with a high risk of rules lawyering and could lead to people twisting/interpreting the rules to try to justify them doing something they want to do that seems ill-advised to the rest of us.  I realize that is likely not your intention, but it is easy to read your question and be worried that any answer to it will be misused like that.  Combining "smells like it might lead to rules lawyering" with "oh no, yet another question about GenAI" has a high risk of leading to kneejerk negative reactions.
So let's back up and start with the general concepts.  There's a ton of skepticism about GenAI and LLMs on Stack Overflow, and I think rightly so.  Many people have had the experience that LLMs are unreliable.  Worse, LLMs are "confident-sounding bullshitters" and often produce answers that are crafted to look convincing even when they are wrong.  They defeat human heuristics for recognizing quality.  This is quite concerning.
Also, questions that get asked on SO are often ones that are more challenging to answer, and thus are where LLMs are the worst (where there is the highest risk of wrong/bad answers or hallucination).
For all of these reasons, people have had bad experiences around LLMs and have bad associations and bad feelings.  And those reactions are justified and based on reality.
Therefore, if you're using a LLM to help you answer a Stack Overflow question, you're already on pretty shaky ground.  I know you want to ask whether it is formally/technically prohibited or not, but I think that's putting the cart before the horse.  Regardless of whether it is allowed, is it even a good idea in the first place?  It seems pretty dubious to me.
And it's especially dangerous to use a LLM to help you answer, if the reason you are using a LLM is because you don't know how to answer the question yourself on your own.  If you don't know how to answer the question yourself, there is a high risk that you won't have the expertise to evaluate candidate answers: you might be fooled by confident-sounding bullshit from the LLM.
Certainly, there are some questions where it is much easier to check whether the answer is correct than to find the answer yourself.  For instance, maybe you can test the proposed code and see whether it works.  For such questions, it might be perfectly fine and valuable to use a LLM to help you come up with a proposed solution, as long as you personally vet that candidate answer carefully yourself and you don't trust the LLM to give you correct answers.
But beware.  I suspect there are many questions where it is non-trivial to evaluate whether an answer is correct.  Maybe you can test whether the code appears to work on an example input, but did your sample input cover all cases and code paths?  Can you check whether the code is portable to other platforms, whether it follows proper idioms and contains appropriate error checks, whether it avoids memory leaks and race conditions?  Are you qualified to verify that it follows appropriate security practices?  For those questions, if you are using AI to help you answer, that's pretty sketchy.
Back to your question about whether it is prohibited.  I don't think this is a helpful question to ask, and I think the best answer is to un-ask the question.  If you try to parse the existing rules, word-by-word, you can try to form some answers or opinions, but the existing rules weren't really written with this question in mind and weren't devised for this purpose.  They were devised to deal with an emergency situation, and it's a mistake to parse their wording carefully to draw inferences about anything beyond that.  If you ask for interpretations of the existing rules to your situation, you're going to get an answer, but it won't be helpful, and it won't be grounded; it'll just be some arbitrary ruling.
Alternatively, perhaps you are suggesting we try to figure out what the policy should be, and asking for the community to identify a policy.  But I don't think this effort is likely to be successful -- at least, not in response to this particular post.  I don't think the time is ripe.  I think negative feelings about GenAI are still too strong; and I think the capabilities of existing LLMs are still a bit too weak; and I think the question is too broad.
More importantly, I don't think the question is crafted in a way that's likely to lead to a productive and definitive answer.  Formulating rules about such a broad concept without any context is too difficult and open-ended.  Site policy is typically driven not by broad philosophical commitments, but by what is most helpful for the site's mission.  And as such, it's hard to propose what would be a good policy without first looking at some concrete examples and specifics of how you plan to use AI to help you.  Until you've provided more information and context on that, it's hard to give the kind of precise answer you seem to be wishing for.  There are just too many different possible ways to use AI, with different implications and risks and issues.
So I'm going to refuse to answer your question, and instead offer you the principles above to guide you in your use of the site.  I know it's not exactly what you were hoping for, but it's what I can offer, to help in the situation you are in.

"it's hard to propose what would be a good policy without first looking at some concrete examples and specifics of how you plan to use AI to help you. Until you've provided more information and context on that" - but I did provide quite a bit of context on what I want to do: I want to flag useful answers of VonC for undeletion where it's obvious they were not written by AI (notwithstanding that VonC may have used AI to research them somehow, and none of us can possibly tell), and I want to provide replacement answers to questions where VonC's answers got nuked, reading his answers first.

(Secondarily, after seeing some of the highly-upvoted comments in response to the question, many now deleted, I would also quite like to confirm that we're not expected to somehow screen our sources for LLM content and that nobody's going to get answers nuked simply because they cited or quoted from a third party source that turns out to have been written with the help of an LLM. The silly extreme example of this I give in the comments is quoting the official docs for a tool in an answer when the dev who wrote the docs has publicly disclosed that they always use Copilot in their editor.)

If you get any use of AI by VonC wrong and use the results in good faith, it would be a violation of the license. You cannot grant CC BY-SA 4.0 to answers from an AI. Even the OpenAI, Google & Co. cannot grant such a license, because the AI possibly infringed on other people's original works.

Another risk is many good people leaving Stackoverflow due to AI use. Loosing a few hundred answers is an acceptable price for the integrity of the platform.

@Sebastian Barring the implausible case that there's a section that's an uncited copy of part of someone else's work, I don't see how an IP problem is gonna exist; at worst, the content will not be copyrightable at all, and readers will have more rights than if it were CC licensed. If it does copy others' work, sure, that's a potential problem, but no more than any non-AI answer that contains plagiarism or indeed quotations. (Notably those of VonC's answers I've looked at are almost entirely made up of cited quotes, which are surely more problematic for licensing than AI content is!)

@MarkAmery, Those are two specific use cases.  I suggest you ask two separate questions, each one about just one of those use cases.  For example, for the first, I suggest you ask a separate question where you ask if you can flag VonC answers for undeletion if you're sure they're not written by AI.  Don't ask "Can I use AI to help me write answers?", which is a much broader question, and loaded with too many other issues.  There is a clear path forward, but the path forward is not by trying to settle the entire broad space of whether you can use AI to help you answer questions.

For your secondary question, about confirming that you're not expected to screen your sources, I think the best approach is to simply not ask.  I just don't think you're going to get any useful answer, or worse, you're going to get a dogmatic answer that is counter-productive.  I understand where you're coming from, I really do, but I don't think it's going to lead to anywhere good.  Or if you really must ask, ask a separate question just about that -- not about the broad topic of using AI to help you write answers.

@IslamHassan, Great!  Glad to hear you are interested in this topic.  I encourage you to think about it, see if you have any proposals, and maybe make a post with a proposal, along with evidence and rationale to support it; or make a discussion post that sets up the problem well.  I don't think this post does the right kind of set-up to lead to a productive discussion of that broad policy space.  Yes, I am avoiding the question, and quite deliberately so, because I don't think the question has been set up well enough to allow a productive discussion (as I tried to explain in my answer).

@D.W. "for the first, I suggest you ask a separate question where you ask if you can flag VonC answers for undeletion if you're sure they're not written by AI. Don't ask "Can I use AI to help me write answers?", which is a much broader question" - no, it's a narrower question. The only way that it could ever make sense to flag VonC's clearly-non-AI-generated posts is if clearly-non-AI-generated posts can be presumed not to violate the AI policy. Thus answering any question about handling VonC's posts necessarily entails determining if research-only use of AI is banned as the first step.

research only use of AI is undetectable. That's like saying we're gonna ban anyone from using W3schools or MDN as a research source. This topic seems absurd to me.

@D.W. (This reasoning for why the question about research-only use is narrower than a question about how to handle VonC's non-AI-generated posts reflects my remark in the question about how Machavity's guidance to flag them effectively expresses a view by Machavity that research-only use of GenAI is permitted. Since we can literally never tell by inspection whether a post used AI for research, even saying it's conceivably, occasionally possible to recognise a post didn't use GenAI and flag it for undeletion logically entails saying that research-only use is not banned "use" per the policy.)

@MarkAmery, You can do as you please. Regardless of whether it is narrower or broader, I am trying to suggest a path that I think has a better chance of a useful outcome. You're already getting un-nuanced answers like ``The answer to any question asking "can I use AI to post [...] on SO" is no'', exactly as I predicted. I don't think that position is good for the site, but it is a predictable reaction, given how the question has been framed here. And now you're arguing with those answers. [...]

To me, that all seems entirely predictable.  I am trying to suggest a direction that I think is more likely to have a positive outcome.  But you're a smart person, I'm sure you have considered these possibilities.  You are free to decide what approach you want to take.  No need to defend your approach to me.

I've said it at the beginning of the GenAI debate in 2022 somewhere and I say it again: GenAI is just a tool and a very unreliable one, and in general simply another resource to draw inspiration from. GenAI output can mislead, but so can any other resources, although GenAI is trusted less than other sources currently. You have to double check all your sources anyway.
People use it however not as a resource, but as a replacement for the human. That is very dangerous, because so far AI is not remotely capable of doing any quality assurance (or real understanding). We want experts. We want the best solutions. Not just something that might or might not work.
GenAI is like an initial brainstorming helper. It might inspire you. But you have to test and make these ideas really work by yourself. And you don't simply become an expert because GenAI said something that sounded reasonable.
Additionally GenAI is also a really bad search engine because it doesn't give information about the origin of the information. Search engines offer lots of links to sites with even more links. GenAI offers almost none of that. As a preliminary search GenAI might be okay, but even then I would check the results again with a real search engine, in order to find authoritative sources by humans (is more difficult now).
I use GenAI for my work as a search engine (reminding me of simple stuff I forgot details about) or as a source of inspiration (what ways are there to achieve something). But I need to be cautious not to rely too much on GenAI, to include all other sources and to test carefully. Testing was never more important.
I think that if GenAI is one of many sources and if it is otherwise completely tested, checked and compared against alternative sources and rewritten by your own words, that usage would be acceptable by me in almost any context.
But I fear that only a very slim minority of people is capable of limiting themselves to this usage and on the other hand non experts (or users addicted to rep on the platform) are tempted to use GenAI in a way that only creates answers of poor/unreliable quality. All in all, GenAI may not have lifted the quality of answers on SE, but rather lowered them.


Is using GenAI for researching an answer banned, even if you don't copy or closely paraphrase any of its output?

Yes, this would run afoul of the policy, which states:

All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.

Note their particular double emphasis on the word "All". In other words, if you can think of a way that generative AI is involved in a post's existence, however removed, you have found yourself in a situation where that post is not allowed on Stack Overflow.


Can VonC post new answers based on his deleted answers as long as they do not copy or close-paraphrase from them?

I'm not sure how VonC could "base" answers on genAI posts without violating the policy. But this is a matter for VonC to bring up with moderators directly, if he cares. It's not anyone else's concern.


Can we post answers based on information from VonC's deleted answers?

No, this runs afoul of the policy, which, again, states:

All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.

Writing an answer that is based on an answer that was written using generative AI is just a longer-winded way of writing an answer that is, ultimately, based on generative AI.

Do you understand the context of the question and can you verify the provided answer? Can you distinguish a good solution from a mediocre one? Can you warn the user of the potential side effects of the given solution? Did you write a piece of code but you don't remember the name of that specific API? If the answer is yes, then you can go ahead
