Why is staging work not (partially) automated?
I do not know if the staging frequency of reviews is matching the frequency of posts, but it seems that reviewing those posts is a work that can be automated, at least partially (e.g., using checklist trees with: Is code is provided? Did you search for existing solutions?).
I have the feeling that staging reviewing is a very repetitive task, with a lot of repetitive subtasks (eg., checking if some code is provided when there is a bug question; commenting with "please read how to ask"), eventually finding duplicates or related questions (this is connected to another problem: search on SO). I think that first posting guiding and reviewing first posts can be to a certain degree automated, fully, partially, or assited with miscellaneous automations.

Is there any effort going in that direction?

Is the review work being used for ML (or something else) research/development and then automation?


ML is extremely wide, therefore I am not necessarily refering to LLM, I am rather thinking about more tunable switches, for instance: defining manually decision trees, and provide easy to manage and compute-light classifiers. SVM, random forests, HMM, kernel based classifiers etc.
To be more explicit and more quantitative, I think that 1-2 fulltime ML researchers with regular computers (no LLVM, no expensive servers) can bring a lot. ML scores are typically living in [0.0-1.0] where 1.0 is 100% match between automatic evaluation and groundtruth; and this groundtruth can be continuously asserted by real developers. In terms of UI, one could have a question, ML scores, and reviewers validating (true|false, or multiclass) the ML choices and ultimating finishing the post review (or something else).
Finding duplicates, or partial copy or tampered/processed "copies" is a very old problem in ML, solved to a certain degree in different ways for content (text, video, images, sound). I am aware that the "duplicate question" has its specificities. I think there should be some effort in that direction to be done.
I think that automation, including checklist trees (which can be manual up to automated (ML trees, random forets etc)), can be progressively added, for the benefit of all.

Is there any possibility for external researchers to have an easier (than crawling) access to SO's content ?


"but it seems that reviewing those posts is a work that can be automatized." it totally can be. If you don't care if it's correct.

"at least partially (eg., is code is provided ?" not all questions need code. Even humans fail on this often, I don't see how a machine would fare better.

@VLAZ Of course it's not a hard coded list. There should a checklist tree.

"using checklists" well that kind of stuff that would be useful as part of the Ask Wizard not really the staging ground.

Just because you can doesn't mean you should. AI has severe accuracy problems still. There's absolutely potential for non-AI automation, but SE hasn't bothered

Who would actually check off the checklist? Automation itself isn't done by just having a checklist, one still needs an automated way to check off each item. The item "did you search for existing solutions?" seems to imply the author would check off items, which is neither automated nor the point of other people reviewing posts in the staging ground.

What exactly would you want to be automated? And how much of that should actually be part of onboarding as opposed to the Staging Ground?

Indeed it could be automated. If by AI, then by a reliable AI. But even automation based on heuristics could work to reduce the drudgery.

@PeterMortensen I guess you are restricting AI to neuron networks, or even only LLM ? AI is much broader, and does not include only convex optimisations. Also, I am against doing eveything with convex optimisation.

As a feature-request I would too find this not clear/detailed enough, but as a discussion it's very well understandable what the topic is.

You just wanted to show off your knowledge of AI-driven automization right ;) I'm fine with that really, it beats the usual "just use AI" type of meta post. But the fact that you know it does not automatically imply that the engineers of the site are capable. Yes it can be done, but should it be done and besides that, is it feasible ? I don't think so regarding the latter two. Maybe 10-15 years from now humanity is in the toddler stage of being able to cope with this kind of technology. Right now, we're still struggling to make build pipelines work reliably.

@Gimby I did not; my text is boringly generic on that aspect. I am convinved it is feasible with not such effort, without LLVM, with sparse funding (time or money). Because I think that the time cost for everybody is still unnecessarily high.

Fair enough. Still fully disagree though. What you describe would be more something you'd do when you create Stack Overflow 2.0. Making such changes in Stack Overflow 1.0 would be the act of introducing multiplayer support in a video game 20 years after the game has been released. Everyone thinks they want it, and everyone will hate it once they have it because it will never meet expectations.

I would actually be pretty interested in how you think this "is feasible with not such effort, without LLVM [sic], with sparse funding". Take for example your check list item of "Is code is provided?" - how would this be meaningfully checked without trivial ways around it?

@MisterMiyagi If the only concern is that people might cheat, then once could maybe engage in a cat and mouse game where examples of people going around are used to add to the training set for the used AI until these avenues are closed. It would then depend on how fast one can catch up. I'm not so worried there. I'm more worried about the usefulness of the supplied code of people not cheating.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I purposely did not use the word "cheat". Though even if I did consider that the main problem area, "engage in a cat and mouse game where examples of people going around are used to add to the training set" is hardly low effort. But at the end of the day, we want relevant code, not some code - it doesn't matter if people fail that due to cheating, inability, or carelessness.

@MisterMiyagi Sure, AI is not as good as an expert reviewer at least at the moment but it could probably help with some half intelligent tasks like giving hints. Things like "good questions like this typically contain more code", "typical minimal code examples are shorter" might already help. This would be more or less the same comment I could give in the staging ground. I also just write sometimes to please include a minimal example.

If you want to automate something, you need to know exactly how it should work; then you would apply AI or any other technology to do what should be done, but faster. However, we haven't got enough experience with Staging Ground. We don't know what exactly it should do. Especially in various corner cases.
Maybe in a few years, when the work would become tedious, you could do it. You would then know what a reasonable person would do in the review UI, and make sure AI does the same.

We've not automated the review queues which have been present since quite some years, why do you think the staging ground can head in that direction? Reviews are quite a subjective matter, maybe there can be some automation but I don't see complete automation coming in any time soon.

That's another question, which I think is good. Why not apply AI to review queues? It looks like a classical task for AI (or course, if you don't intend to force it) — you have a lot of work to be done and a lot of data to verify AI's actions. Maybe it could handle 70% of reviews where the required action is obvious. Or 10%? I don't know. As far as I know, there is some automation which processes spam, and it's quite successful.

"Why not apply AI to review queues?" I'm decently sure unpaid volunteers are cheaper than training and deploying AI.

"Maybe it could handle 70% of reviews where the required action is obvious" how would an AI know the required action is obvious? AI is inaccurate, and it can not with 100% certainty know what it should do.

@Cerbrus AI starts with if/else switches. It can be exact.

That's so far from how AI works... No. AI is never exact. It's always a guess. It's always an estimate. You can never trust AI to be 100% accurate. It may get darn close, but it doesn't do facts.


Is there any effort going in that direction?

None that was made public and that I'm aware of and I'm interested in that direction and a kind of regular reader. But I may have missed something.
The only ML thing I remember is the Unfriendly comments detection robot by Kevin Montrose and coworkers in 2019/2020. It worked quite well. And maybe something with related questions and a question formatting assitant both in 2023. Especially the question formatting was a catastrophe.
There is room but the effort to get a good result may be significantly higher than you think. I personally would like to see more automatic duplicate detection because I think that LLMs could do that very well. The final decision should remain with the content curators but it would solve a really hard problem we frequently face: memorizing and finding duplicates candidates (reinventing the wheel might be faster for us humans).
Will the company go along these lines? I doubt it.

Finding duplicates, or partial copy or tampered/processed "copies" is a very old problem in ML, solved to a certain degree in different ways for content (text, video, images, sound). I am aware that the "duplicate question" has its specificities, but I suspect there is no one enough skilled (sorry, should I say "enough funding") to address the duplicated questions problem on SO.

@Soleil Maybe there isn't one. With that many million questions and the Q&As being the building blocks of a library of knowledge I would have expected more emphasis on the connections between the these blocks. Being duplicates or related or classification (debugging, howto, subtask) would have been interesting avenues to explore, especially now with LLMs.

In general I think that new technologies should be used responsibly but they also should be used. On the one hand there is mistakes to be made but on the other hand inertia just keeps people from progressing. The old ways aren't the best. The best is responsible use of everything that is available. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430191/can-i-use-ai-to-help-me-answer-as-long-as-the-actual-content-isnt-ai-generated
